# LinkedIn Post API: post text get's cut off if contains "()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, escaping, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post on LinkedIn via their API.
Endpoint `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts`.

The integration is working fine until I try to post something with a `(` character. Redigated example:

```
  {
  author: '',
  commentary: 'a line\n' +
    '\n' +
    'another line...\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\n' +
    'This gets posted (it will get cut off from here)\n' +
    'another line\n'
  ...
}
```

If tried url encoding the string as well as JSON.stringify the whole object.
The first gets posted with all the escaped characters still there (i.e.: `a%20line%20`) and will also get cut off since encodeURI doesn't escape `()`.
The latter will throw an error in the API saying something like "commentary string formatted wrong".

Any ideas how to solve this?

Edit:

This here mentions the escapes at the very bottom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/little-text-format?view=li-lms-2022-08#text

However: If I do `\\(` the API will come back with `"The input string format is invalid"`

Comment: can you try backslash before `(` or `)`? like `\(` and `\)`

Comment: @BenchVue thanks, yeah I had tried that as well. I get the following response from the API:

`{
    "code": "ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "Request body could not be converted to data map"
}`

Comment: I have no credential LinkedIn, I can't test my self. That is my problem. I have no idea without my local testing.

Comment: Can you try double quoting the escape sequence?

Comment: @MatJ how do you mean? `"\\("`? Would break the json syntax unless I also escape th `"` 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was indeed some weird escaping stuff.

Solved by running `text.replace(/[\(*\)\[\]\{\}<>@|~_]/gm, (x) => "\\" + x)` on the string.

Comment: I was getting this error with the new `rest/posts` api with a basic text block and link. This replace block fixed the issue!

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered same issue and here's how i fixed it in PHP:

```
$sanitizedDescription = preg_replace_callback('/([\(\)\{\}\[\]])|([@*<>\\\\\_~])/m', function ($matches) {
    return '\\'.$matches[0];
    }, $descriptionToSanitize);
```

What the above code snippet does is it matches every special character mentioned in the regex and replaces them with escape char so that they are treated as literals by LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is looking for a solution in Python.

```py
def escape_text(text):
    chars = ["\\", "|", "{", "}", "@", "[", "]", "(", ")", "<", ">", "#", "*", "_", "~"]
    for char in chars:
        text = text.replace(char, "\\"+char)
    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn text gets cut off with "()" or "|"

I have fixed it with PHP like this:

```
function convertToLittleTextFormat($string) {

    $reservedCharacters = array(
        "\\|",
        "\\{",
        "\\}",
        "\\@",
        "\\[",
        "\\]",
        "\\(",
        "\\)",
        "\\<",
        "\\>",
        "\\#",
        "\\\\",
        "\\*",
        "\\_",
        "\\~"
    );

    // Regular expression pattern to match reserved characters
    $pattern = '/(' . implode('|', $reservedCharacters) . ')/';

    // Escaping reserved characters
    $escapedString = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
        return '\\' . $matches[0];
    }, $string);


    return $escapedString;
}
```

For more details please check the official documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/little-text-format?view=li-lms-2024-01#language-grammar)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `\` to escape the `(`

Example:

```
This gets posted \(it will not get cut off from here\)
```